# placing routerLInk on a tag but a tag not clickable angular 6

Tags: html, angular, anchor

I have a bunch of links

html

```
<div class="col-12 navlinks">
        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="justify-content-center">
            <a class="col-auto d-inline-block whitelink" routerLink="/team">The Team</a>
            <a class="col-auto d-inline-block whitelink" routerLink="/privacy">Privacy</a>
            <a class="col-auto d-inline-block whitelink" routerLink="/terms">Terms</a>
            <a class="col-auto d-inline-block whitelink" routerLink="/contact">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

css

```
.navlinks{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.whitelink{
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

now the cursor is not turning into a pointer
and clicking the links does nothing.

the routes and all other requirements for these links to work are correctly implemented. Its just for some reason these links think they are special. I am guessing their parents spoiled them rotten. Not sure, either way I am trying to get them back on track otherwise I am going to send them off on marine corps boot camp to shape them up....

Why For this?

Comment: Could you provide your app.module.ts? Does it look like `const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'team', component: YourTeamComponent },
  { path: 'privacy', component: YourPrivacyComponent },
];` ?

Comment: @Maarti yep yep yep yep yep yep yep!

Comment: have you imported the routes module and passed the routes array  to the for Root method of the module it looks like this 
`@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],

})`

Answer (score 0):

I can see the cursor with the exact same code you have! Try changing color property of whitelink class to black if you have white background!

```
.whitelink{
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Also, make sure you have the routes defined for the routerlink paths!

Comment: so unfortunatly this is not the solve at all. It seems the site is treating this as a p tag rather than a a tag no idea why.